# Key (num_dossier, arrondissement_id)=(161/17, 12) is duplicated PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, constraints, odoo

I'm getting the following error with this constraint:

```
_sql_constraints = [
    ('num_dossier_uniq', 'unique(num_dossier,arrondissement_id)', 'Numéro de dossier doit etre unique par Arrondissement')
]
```

The error when I insert the new values:

```
ERROR: could not create unique index "num_dossier_uniq"
État SQL :23505
Détail :Key (num_dossier, arrondissement_id)=(161/17, 12) is duplicated.
```

I don't know how to solve this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to add unique constraint on model/table. But you have already same data in model.

First you need to update your existing same data with unique and then upgrade your module. Afterwards, unique constraints will work as you expected.